# What am I doing wrong in this Twilioquest exercise?(beginner in JavaScript)

Tags: javascript

This is my first post on this forum! I'd like some help regarding a beginner JavaScript exercise on the application TwilioQuest, which is a sort of game-like app that teaches you code along the way.  Regarding my level of skill in coding, I completed all the beginner/free lessons on Codecademy for Java(i think), but that's as far as it goes.  Until yesterday I didn't know Java and Javascript were two different things, so I'm not familiar with the JavaScript exercises on Twilioquest.

In the second training mission of TwilioQuest, JavaScript test lab, it requires me to "hack" some laser beams by completing an exercise.  I am stuck on the exercise that allows me to enter the lead scientist's office and retrieve a password on a piece of paper.  The exercise wants me to create a file called divideByTwo.js, which is supposed to take an inputted number and give half of it as the output.  It gives me most of the code required, which is:

```
const argumentValue = process.argv[2];
const numberValue = Number(argumentValue);
const result = numberValue / 2;
console.log(42);
```

Then, it tells me to change the last line of the code in order to make the program run.  I then made the following change:

```
console.log(result);
```

because console.log() is used to print out whatever is in the parenthesis.  But this is wrong, and I have already tried things like `console.log(numberValue /2);` and `console.log("result");`.  I didn't expect them to work, and they didn't, but I really don't know why console.log(result); is wrong.  Also, I had a little trouble creating the entire file divideByTwo.js and putting it in the correct folder at first, so I'm wondering if that might be part of the problem at all. Thank you for any responses!

Comment: Hello! This question might be a better fit for somewhere like [r/javascript](https://www.reddit.com/r/javascript/) or [r/learnprogramming](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnprogramming/). Stack Overflow is usually more for questions about specific problems, (ex, "when I run this code, I get this error; why?"). Without knowing more about Twilioquest, and more importantly, without knowing more about what error message you're getting, we're not going to be help you.

Comment: Fwiw, your code looks fine. My advice would be that if you're getting an error, google the error. If you're not getting an error but it's marking your question as wrong, it might be that the test runner expects specific output (ex, don't print the 42).

Either way, best of luck learning to code!

Comment: okay, thanks! other people have confirmed that the code itself is correct as well, and i tried changing it to return result; instead, but it still doesn't work.  would it be helpful if i posted the entire prompt here?

Comment: also, the prompt says i should test it in the terminal to see if it works.  when i type in: node divideByTwo.js 400 in the terminal, nothing prints out, so the problem might be because of that?

Comment: If when you enter `node divideByTwo.js 400` you get no output, there's a more fundamental issue here, like you're typing the code into the file but not actually saving the file. There should be _some_ output from running the script. Try `cat divideByTwo.js` to print the file contents and make sure you're running what you think you are. More generally, you want to get some kind of output from running the script, even if it's an error message.

Comment: i typed cat divideByTwo.js into the terminal and nothing happened, so that's probably the problem.  the thing is, i have the file on autosave and i also manually saved it after every edit i made and before every time i tested it.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the exact prompt it's hard to determine what it really wants. From the looks of it, console.log(result) should correctly print the answer. Maybe it wants the function to return an answer in which case you would use `return result` instead of `console.log(result)`

Answer (score 0):

I've created a snippet of what you might be talking about. Without full context, this is kind of a guessing game until we know what answer the game is expecting.

If you run the script below it is doing exactly what you describe:

```js
//here is the process object with array argv
//within the argv array there are 3 numbers
var process = {  
argv: [0,10,42]
};

//here we are targeting the third number in the array
//we target index [2] since javascript is 0-based and arrays start at index 0
//index 2 is the number 42
const argumentValue = process.argv[2];
const numberValue = Number(argumentValue);
const result = numberValue / 2;

//result is half of the targeted index 
console.log(result);
//output 21
```

The code itself is correct but may not be working because the game wants a different answer.

Comment: Hello! the game actually provided some links to help me with the exercise, and it seems like i need to use something like process.argv.  after reading the links, i still don't really understand exactly what this does, but it seems like it's a command that returns an array of all the inputs put into a file of code? since argv is the name of the file they were using as an example, i tried putting console.log(process.divideByTwo);, but it still didn't work?

Comment: also, when i tried to access(?) the file through the terminal by using /User/(my name on my computer)/quest(the name of the folder i stored the file in)/divideByTwo.js, it said -bash permission denied.  what does this mean?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if you're still stuck on this but so was I! I used the links and the one called "How to parse command line arguments" helped me out big time. Here was my last line of code: console.log('numberValue', numberValue / 2);

It worked for me, so hopefully this is your solution too!

Answer (score 0):

After reading all your posts I tried using these lines and it worked!

```
const argumentValue = process.argv[2];
const numberValue = Number(argumentValue);
const result = numberValue / 2;
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you're saving your files, as that can also cause problems. Also, since you mentioned having some trouble making the files, I'd recommend using an IDE like VSCode, the UI makes it easy to make new files within the folder you're working with, and this helped me a lot with organizing my code for the Python and JS portions of TwilioQuest!